# How to Disable SharePoint form field in forms through designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

How can I Disable input fields in forms through SharePoint Designer.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the form in SharePoint Designer and go to the Code view.

On your Mentor Name field change the ControlMode attributes from "Edit" to 'Display".  There should be 2 occurrences:

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('u',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>

<SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff1description{$Pos}" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="Display"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ControlMode="Display" does not work when the ControlMode for this form is "new"; if that is the case then using jquery in this manner will do the same:

`$('selector').attr('disabled','disabled')`

Answer (score 0):

[Lost in Alabama's](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/15198/) solution works in SP2010 for new forms as well as edit forms; you shouldn't need jQuery for this.

You will, however, need to create a new New Item form and then edit in code view, replacing ControlMode="New" with ControlMode="Display".  And of course these shouldn't be required fields.

Here is a New Item form example for an entire row:

```
<tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>Supplier</nobr>
        </H3>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff16{$Pos}" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Supplier" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff16',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Supplier')}"/>
        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff16description{$Pos}" FieldName="Supplier" ControlMode="Display"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Result:
[image]

If you want to *hide* the field you can simply change the class to "ms-hidden" for both class fields, example:

```
<tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-hidden">
        <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
            <nobr>Supplier</nobr>
        </H3>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-hidden">
        <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff16{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Supplier" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff16',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Supplier')}"/>
        <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff16description{$Pos}" FieldName="Supplier" ControlMode="New"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Result:
[image]